# Need to add data from deleted rowkey in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

Unfortunately i deleted the rowkey.

Eg : delete from tablename where key='rowkey';

After deleted the row key all the data are deleted.

Note : The table is counter table.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  KEY text PRIMARY KEY
) WITH
  comment='' AND
  comparator=text AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  default_validation=counter AND
  min_compaction_threshold=4 AND
  max_compaction_threshold=32 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  compaction_strategy_class='SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' AND
  compression_parameters:sstable_compression='SnappyCompressor';
```

After deleted the rowkey i can't insert the data for the same key.I am able to update the data for some other keys.

Eg : update tablename set new = new + 1 where key='2014';

i didn't find any entry for 2014

Expected : I need to add the data for the deleted rowkey.

Answer (score 0):

Counter removal is strongly limited: from Counters Wiki documentation:

> if you delete a row of counters, incrementing any counter in that row
>   (that existed before the deletion) will result in an undetermined
>   behavior.

On the [counters wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Counters) you can find more information.

BTW: upcoming 2.1 (and future 3.0) will make a small revolution on how counters works, so if you have to work with counters you'd better use newest cassandra version (2.1 is now RC5)